# opendj scheduled task to clean up historical data

Tags: opendj

I'd like to set up a scheduled task(or cron job) in OpenDJ to clean up some historical data (queried out from ldap filter).

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a scheduled task in OpenDJ (rather than system level cron job) to perform such clean-up ?

If yes, how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is something you can do out of the box.
It might be possible with custom plugins.